# Hex file and disassembly discrepancy

Tags: pic, microchip, hex-file

I have parsed hex files for the purpose of bootloading before.  This is my first time with a hex file generated using Microchip's XC32 tool chain.  Right away I noticed what appears to be a discrepancy between the hex file and the disassembly.

The first 3 lines of the hex file:

```
:020000040000fa
:020000041d00dd
:10000000030000100000000040f3060000000000a4
```

From the listing file:

```
9d000000 <_reset>:
9d000000: 10000003 b 9d000010 <__reset_switch_isa>
9d000004: 00000000 nop

9d000008 <__reset_micromips_isa>:
9d000008: f340 0006 jalx 9d000018 <_startup>
9d00000c: 0000 0000 nop
```

Notice that address 9d000008 looks like it should contain 0x06 in the listing file.  However, the hex file seems to indicate 0x40 at this location.  The following 3 bytes are also not in the expected order.

:10     0000     00     03 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 **40 f3 06 00** 00 00 00 00    a4

When I look though the file other records are as expected, but the bytes pertaining to this `jalx` instruction word seem to be out of order.  Can someone set me straight?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
Another perplexing data point.  If I flash the hex file into the part using the debugger (not using my bootloader).  Then if I view the execution memory and disassembly listing, I see the following:

```
Address     Instruction     Disassembly
1D00_0000   10000003        BEQ ZERO, ZERO, 0x1D000010
1D00_0004   00000000        NOP
1D00_0008   0006F340        SLL S8, A2, 13
1D00_000C   00000000        NOP
```

When the IDE reinterprets the code that it programmed in, it now shows a `SLL` instruction not a `JALX`.  This is compiler generated startup code so I cannot be sure what it should be.  The byte order matches the hex file not the listing file, so the Microchip tools interpret the hex file as I would but this does not match the listing file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this question on the microchip.com forum and a couple users there provided the answer.

Basically the `JALX` instruction in the listing file excerpt is formatted in microMIPS not MIPS32.  So there is not actually a discrepancy between the listing file and the hex file.  The hex file is interpreted with each byte written into ascending address locations as I was attempting to do.  However, viewing the disassembly as I did in the update does no interpret the instructions as microMIPS, so the disassembly for that instruction is incorrect when viewed through the IDE.  When the `JALX` is executed, a flag in the CPU informs the processor to treat this instruction as mircoMIPS.

For more information, see the excellent responses I received at:

http://www.microchip.com/forums/FindPost/986740

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the listing is using Little Endian for those 16-bit values.  If that were meant to be a 32-bit value, the 0x06 would come first.

As long as that's the case, there's not really a problem.

Comment: The hex file is in Intel format.  If the 8th byte after the : is only 0 or 1, then it is I8=16 bit.  If it is is 0 to 3, then is is I16=20 bit.  if it is only 0, 1, 4, 5 then it is I32=32 bit.  Microchip normally uses I8.

Comment: @cup. Thanks for your input.  All of the Microchip generated hex files I have seen have been I32.  In the snippet that I posted above the first 2 records are type 4 to allow 32 bit addressing.

Comment: @donjuedo, Thanks for your response.  I am definitely not an expert, but I have only ever seen bytes listed in consecutive order by ascending address in data records.  If that can change how would an interpreter know?  Based on the updated information I posted, I do not think that is happening in this case.

Comment: Maybe it is simply some reading aid for the listing, and is the 32-bit instruction mostly split in a 16-bit opcode + a 16-bit immediate value. (or combination of register identifiers). Such notation then makes it easier readable